# 'certificate verify failed' when using PyFCM to send a Push Notification

Tags: python-2.7, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

I'm trying to send push notifications via PyFCM (via Firebase Cloud Messaging).

When I tried to do this initially, I got the SNIMMissingWarning telling me that the request to the Firebase server was insecure.

I upgraded packages to handle this, but now I'm stuck with a 'certificate_verify_failed' error.

I went through the PyFCM code and found that it was using the requests module to send a request to the server.

I know that this issue is related to not having the CA certificates for the Firebase server, but have no idea how to get these certificates and setup the requests module to use them.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem, sharing it for the benefit of others,

Apart from installing `requests[security]`, I needed to install `libssl-dev` via

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

So the overall setup for this is, first install the development versions of ffi and ssl libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

Then, install `requests[security]`

```
pip install requests[security]
```

Comment: The steps should be reversed; you first install the OS dependencies `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev`, then you install the Python code that relies on these dependencies `pip install requests[security]`

Comment: Thanks! Edited my answer to reflect this