# Application fails to verify SSL self-signed certificate on a BeagleBone Black running Debian

Tags: python, debian, ssl-certificate, beagleboneblack, self-signed

The following code is working fine in my Ubuntu machine (Python 2.7.6):

```
r = requests.get(GET_URL, verify=certificate_path)
```

When I run this code in my BeagleboneBlack with Debian, I get this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:100:
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents 
urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections 
to fail.

For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
#insecureplatformwarning.   InsecurePlatformWarning

[Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: 
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

The certificate_path has the path to a self-signed certificate. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible fix there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package

Comment: have you tried these answers  ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405867/how-to-get-python-requests-to-trust-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: Quick fix for you at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074813/certificate-verify-failed-when-using-pyfcm-to-send-a-push-notification, I ran into this issue with PyFCM a couple of days back

Comment: @nuriselcuk , I tried the suggested in your link, without success.

Comment: @Mostafa , I think you did not read well my explanation, because I had already done what is supposed to do in your suggestion.

Comment: @Bitonator , your suggestion did not work for me too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After search more and try some alternatives, including the suggested ones in the comments, I found this link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/549679/issued-certificate-not-yet-valid-with-wget

The problem was the **system clock** set to a **date in the past**.

Just corrected the date with the following command and it worked for  me:

```
$ ntpdate gps.ntp.br
```